# Computer lost sound after replacing Graphics Card

Tags: windows-7, audio, graphics-card

At work yesterday I had to replace a graphic card on a computer and by doing so the computer lost the ability to output sounds.

I'm looking at the Windows sound properties and I see no playback devices (I have show disabled/disconnected devices). When going to the Device Manager I see 4 NVIDIA High Definition Audio entries but they don't seem to do much. The new card is an NVIDIA Quadro 4000, two DisplayPort outputs and a DVI. I tried re-installing the audio drivers from Dell and they are too old to be installed on Windows 7. I did install the new GPU drivers but it didn't do anything to the sound.

This is a work environement so I can't install speakers on workstations. Users mostly use headphones.

What can I do to get sound back ?

Comment: Are you sure your speakers are just not muted?

Comment: So you installed the drivers form Dell? I would not recommend this, as at times the Dell drivers page can get out of date quickly. Instead try getting the driver directly from NVIDIA.

Comment: My bad, I tried re-installing the audio drivers from Dell by removing the old driver and installing the driver again. The old drivers were installed when we were on Windows XP and I guess it kept on working after the Windows 7 upgrade but it seems to have a block in the installer so I can't get it back.

Comment: Also to note, only the audio driver were installed from Dell. The video driver was downloaded from NVIDIA.

Comment: @Tristan Dube What cable are you using? Do you connect headphones to your screen or to your case sound output ?

Comment: The headphones are connected to the front panel of the computer, there is no audio jack on the screens. The cable is a standard audio cable that fits most computers and phones.

Answer (score 1):

The solution turned out to be : downloading the audio drivers from realtek directly since they were outdated on Dell. Restart and go to the BIOS, I had to force the "Integrated Audio" to ON instead of AUTO. I'm not sure why AUTO did not offer my any audio devices in Windows but there we go.

This must have been because the previous graphic card was handling the audio and offering me the virtual audio devices and the BIOS did not switch back to integrated audio when the card was replaced.

Comment: I'm thinking the opposite.  The new card grabbed the audio and the integrated system shut down.